# How to unit test initialcontext local member of a local method

Tags: junit4

My code looks as such

```
 Private void do lookup(){ 
   Context ctx;
   Try{ 
       ctx = new InitialContext();
       sampref = ctx.lookup("ejb/objEjb");

    }catch{exception ex){
   .....
     }
}
```

The method invoked as part of inner method flow. Please let me know how dz should be handled.
   Since junit run, by doing some "System.setproperty("...") " earlier can v override the initialcontext. I just read somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yuo have few options

1 try to inverse the dependency: instead of having the lookup method (or its caller actually) creating the context you can create the context outside and pass it as a dependency/parameter

2 like above, but you can pass a factory to create a context, so that you can use a mocked factory and return whatever context you want

3 using a test tool like mockito you can spy the instance you want to test, you move the creation of the context to a protected method that you can stub (you don't care to test test the creation of the context itself) so that you can return a mock context

4 using a test  tool like powermockito you can stub the call to a static factory method in the InitialContext class and than return a mock context, something like InitialContext.create();